# Question on the existence of a prime ideal contained in the $\ker$ of a homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}[t]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I found this exercise in a basic algebraic geometry book:

Let $f:\mathbb{C}[x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[t]$ a non-zero homomorphism such that $\ker f$ strictly contains a prime ideal $P\neq0$.

Is it true that $\text{im}\ f=\mathbb{C}$?

I have the feeling it is.

I tried an absurd, noticing that if $\{0\}\neq\text{im}\ f\neq\mathbb{C}$, then $\text{im}\ f$ is prime but not maximal, but since I could not go much further, I guess I'm missing either a result or an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\CC}{{\mathbb C}}$
$\newcommand{\im}{\text{im}}$

First $\CC[x,y]/(\ker f) \subseteq \CC[t]$. So as $\CC[t]$ is a domain $Q=\ker f$ must be a prime of $\CC[x,y]$. So we have a chain of strict inclusions
$(0) \subsetneq P \subsetneq Q$. As $\dim \CC[x,y] = 2$ the ideal $Q$ must be maximal in $\CC[x,y]$. Therefore $\CC[x,y]/Q = \CC$ and $\im f = \CC$.